# Encryption strategy for Amazon S3?

Tags: encryption, truecrypt, amazon-s3

I'm running Windows and strongly considering using Amazon S3 to back up some of my more important data, but i'm having trouble coming up with a good encryption strategy.  I'm a fan of Truecypt and use it locally but it sounds incredibly inefficient to use over S3.  For example, if I want to work on some photos that are in a 5GB container i'd have to download the entire container to mount it.  Costly and impractical.

I've heard of Duplicity and it sounds like a good option, but i'd rather have a more elegant solution that doesn't involve cygwin.  What are my options?

Comment: Do you need the files to be encrypted on your own hard drive, as well as on S3? If not then Dropbox, for example, will encrypt each individual file before it leaves your PC.

Comment: Dropbox's pricing options are a bit too much.  I'd prefer to use Amazon S3 as-is, pay for what I actually use.

Comment: Also bear in mind that Dropbox hold the keys for the encryption, not you, and so you are not the only person with access to your files. If you trust Dropbox, that's fine, but it's worth bearing in mind.

Answer (score 3):

My two cents go to [Jungledisk](https://www.jungledisk.com/personal/).  The interface is great, it will plug right into S3 and works great in a Windows ecosystem

Comment: How would this encrypt the files though?

Comment: Jungle disk has had crazy encryption since back in 06.  The encrypt each file with a different 256bit AES key instead of the entire "package"  http://blog.jungledisk.com/2006/06/06/encryption/